# Presto Query through ELB error "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS"

Tags: amazon-elb, presto

When use an AWS ELB (Elastic Load Balancer) with HTTPS listener that forward the request to the presto cluster (0.193) behind that runs on HTTP, Java client that uses presto-jdbc (0.213) fails to execute select query due to "plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:274)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.execute(PrestoStatement.java:227)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.executeQuery(PrestoStatement.java:76)
    at com.DpTool.executeJdbcQuerySsl(DpTool.java:332)
    at com.DpTool.prestoJdbcSsl(DpTool.java:315)
    at com.DpTool.main(DpTool.java:520)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error fetching next at http://cluster-elb.mydomain:8443/v1/statement/20181120_215602_00038_57ryf/1 returned an invalid response: JsonResponse{statusCode=400, statusMessage=Bad Request, headers={connection=[close], content-length=[236], content-type=[text/html], date=[Tue, 20 Nov 2018 21:56:02 GMT], server=[awselb/2.0]}, hasValue=false} [Error: <html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
</body>
</html>
]
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.client.StatementClientV1.requestFailedException(StatementClientV1.java:436)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.client.StatementClientV1.advance(StatementClientV1.java:383)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.getColumns(PrestoResultSet.java:1742)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.<init>(PrestoResultSet.java:119)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:249)
    ... 5 more
```

It appears that StatementClientV1.advance code try to visit "http://cluster-elb.mydomain:8443/..." which is the ELB address except it should be "https" instead of "http" prefix. The same client code works fine when execute query directly to another HTTPS presto cluster (no ELB). Here is the client Java code. url is "cluster-elb.mydomain:8443"

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("SSL", "true");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String query = "select cluster, query_text from mytable where ds='2018-10-20' limit 10";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Why the presto-jdbc client code is confused and how to make the query work?

Answer (score 1):

This should work in newer versions of Presto. Try it with 0.213.

Comment: I can not quickly try 0.213 yet as the Qubole presto cluster is 0.193 (and as if it is the latest version Qubole support). Do you have a reference of the related commit or other context for review and potential cherry-pick?

Comment: This is probably the one: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/8232

Comment: @danzhi 0.193 is already quite old. I strongly recommend upgrading. Alternatively you can 
use `presto-proxy` for TLS termination. BTW, can you apply custom patches while on Qubole platform?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is due to https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/8232 where the nextUri field in QueryStatusInfo is incorrectly set as http instead of https by presto server (when client talk to presto through elb or proxy).

Comment: This issue was fixed a long time ago.  The related change was closed, but the attached issue was not.  I have closed the issue.